# RecursionError when two items have each other as a field

Tags: python-3.7, python-dataclasses

I'm playing around with dataclasses and found that circular properties lead to problems when using representation methods such as `asdict`. In the example below, we create two `Word`s and place them inside each other's `linked_word` field. When we try to create a dict out of one of those words, that will lead to a recursion error because their properties keep referring to each other endlessly. However, I am not sure how to deal with this.

```py
from __future__ import annotations
import dataclasses
from typing import Optional


@dataclasses.dataclass
class Word:
    text: str
    linked_word: Optional[Word] = None

hello = Word("hello")
world = Word("world")

hello.linked_word = world
world.linked_word = hello

print(dataclasses.asdict(world))  # will throw RecursionError
```

I am not sure whether this problem is unique to the representation functions in `dataclasses` (`asdict`, `astuple`), or whether this is simply "not allowed" as a whole in dataclasses (I don't think so).

The main goal is, then, to either be able to use `asdict` in such a way that the offending properties are *not* included (avoiding the error altogether), or to be able to overwrite the `asdict` method so that I can give a better error message to my users stating that this object cannot be used inside `asdict`.

Comment: What is the question?  What is the expected output?

Comment: My bad, I went over it too quickly. I updated my post. Ideally I would be able to choose which properties are included in `asdict` but if that is not possible, I'd like to at least be able to change the error message whenever someone uses `asdict` on this object because a RecursionError might not be clear from the onset.

Comment: `RecursionError` actually seems to be a sensible behavior here, since `dataclasses.asdict` tries not to leave any reference chains (it uses deep-copy). If you don't want the deep copy, maybe you should just use `vars(world)` instead..

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that it is expected. I just fear that external users using my libraries will try to use `asdict` and the RecursionError is not immediately clear to others. I would've loved it if, instead, all dataclasses had their own method `asdict` that you could overwrite.

Comment: Hmm, yes, that is how [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._asdict) decided to do it - however unlike dataclasses it does not recurse the data, only a shallow dict would be returned.  I'm not really sure the best behavior here, although probably unhandled `RecursionError` is what I'd want anyway. Not convinced that changing the error message would make anything clearer, it's already pretty clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the recursion error is normal because you give same parent as a child. if you use same World class as 2 order child the result goes to infinity recursion. You need to change your child class, you can look at like solution;

```py
from __future__ import annotations
import dataclasses
from typing import Optional


@dataclasses.dataclass
class Word:
    text: str
    linked_word: Optional[Word] = None

hello = Word("hello")
world = Word("world")
obbs = Word("obstacle")

hello.linked_word = world
#world.linked_word = hello # its normal to give recursion error because 
                           # you give same class (world) as a child
obbs.linked_word = hello

print(dataclasses.asdict(obbs))  # will NOT throw RecursionError
```

results:
`{'text': 'obstacle', 'linked_word': {'text': 'hello', 'linked_word': {'text': 'world', 'linked_word': None}}}`

if we came back to main goal of question, you can write a pre check code for preventing recursion, before the inheritance  check all child of data-class :)

i hope it will work for you,
regards